# Compare 2 files and remove duplicate lines only once

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to remove the duplicate values from file 1 comparing with file 2 . When i was trying to do so , i am facing issue like since the value in file 2(c,g) also comes under [b] in file 1 , those are also getting deleted. but my requirement is to delete only those under [a]. Thanks

```
$ less file 1
[a]
c
g
d
[b]
c
g
h
```

and

```
$ less file 2
[a]
c
g
d
```

Comment: and your desired output is ...?

Comment: `grep -v -f file2 file1` ..... although it can lead to false positives

Comment: @glennjackman has an excellent point - I could imagine several variations of what you want output. Also, though - can file2 contain multiple blocks or always 1? What would the output be if the first line of file2 was `[b]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/^\[.*?\]/{s=$0} FNR==NR{seen[s,$0]++; next} !seen[s,$0]' file2 file1
[b]
c
g
h
```

This awk is using an associative array `seen` with a composite key of value inside `[...]` and all the subsequent records i.e. `s,$0`

While going through file2 it saves those value in array and while traversing through file1 it will print only those that aren't available in `seen` thus avoiding duplicates.